# K&R C function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I was reading K&R book (first time) I came across a function using pointers.

Function call

```
qsort(
    (void **)lineptr,
    0,
    nlines-1,
    (int (*)(void *,void *)) (numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
);
```

What I understood is that based on the `numeric` either the address of `strcmp` or `numcmp` is passed and the address is type casted to `(int (*)(void *,void *))` as required for the function.

Function defintion

```
void qsort(void *v[],int left,int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *))
```

So is my interpretation correct regarding the function pointer??

Comment: Can you specify our question a bit? Or am I the only one who doesn't really get, what you are asking?

Comment: yes, interpretation is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's right.

The cast is needed since `strcmp()` takes `const char *` arguments, but they are safe to convert to `void *`.

If you look at [the current manual page for `qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) you can see that the callback's arguments should really be `const void *`, not just `void *` but that's a safe conversion too (as long as the callback treats the pointer as pointer to `const`, of course).

Comment: That only holds true for pointers right?, you can't to that if strcmp() returned something else that `int`.

Comment: @self. Correct, at least in part since the risk of size-changes for different types increases.